# Repetição de if/else como reduzir e melhorar o código?

Tags: c#

Estou iniciando na programação e me surgiu uma dúvida durante as minhas condições. Eu faço uma verificação de quantas vezes deu verdadeiro o resultado, e quantas vezes deu falso. Problema é que não está me dando o resultado de verdade.

A única forma que encontrei para funcionar é a seguinte:

```
if (Lstr_Resultado1 == "Verdadeiro")
{
    Lint_TotalVerdadeiro++;
}
else
{
    Lint_TotalFalso++;
}
if (Lstr_Resultado2 == "Verdadeiro")
{
    Lint_TotalVerdadeiro++;
}
else
{
    Lint_TotalFalso++;
}
if (Lstr_Resultado3 == "Verdadeiro")
{
    Lint_TotalVerdadeiro++;
}
else
{
    Lint_TotalFalso++;
}
```

Acredito que exista uma forma mais performática para se fazer isso. Sei que estou iniciando e a aplicação é simples mas procuro reduzir o uso de processamento da máquina. Qual seria a melhor forma de resolver essa quantia de if / else?

Comment: Você não pode mudar sua pergunta. Se tem uma dúvida nova faça uma pergunta nova. Provavelmente seu código pode ser bem melhor que isto mesmo, mas na sua pergunta original não tinha nada disto, as pessoas não podem ter que ficar adaptando as respostas cada vez que você muda a pergunta.

Comment: Falta contexto e respostas criando estruturas não é nada performático. Mas como falta contexto, talvez possa ser isso.

Comment: @Maniero Certo. foi uma nova duvida que já foi solucionada.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Você pode adicionar os seus resultados em uma `lista` do tipo do seu resultado (string, int, etc...), depois fazer um `foreach` para percorrer sua lista realizando a verificação se o campo é verdadeiro ou não:

```
var resultados = new List<String>();

resultados.Add(Lstr_Resultado1);

foreach (var resultado in resultados)
{
  if(resultado == "Verdadeiro")
    Lint_TotalVerdadeiro++;
  else
    Lint_TotalFalso++;
}
```

Comment: Eu sugiro a mesma coisa, mas deveria transformar esse Lstr_Resultado1...2...3 em um único array e depois fazer um for pra incrementar o total verdadeiro/falso, a não ser que possua sempre apenas três lstr_resultados

Comment: Consegui adicionando o 
resultados.Add(Lstr_Resultado2)
resultados.Add(Lstr_Resultado3)
e arrumando os parâmetros do foreach (var resultado in resultados), não sei porque fez diferença mas estava dando erro antes

Comment: Só uma dúvida, em seu teste você valida três "campos"/variáveis. Sempre será essas três ou tem pode ser "N"?

Comment: @PedroDuca é isso mesmo, eu troquei sem querer (já corrigi), é pq você basicamente declara uma variável `resultado` e utiliza o `in` para percorrer a lista de `resultados`.

Comment: @LeandroAmarilha Sempre será essas três

Comment: @PedroDuca, então não vejo a necessidade de criar mais uma variável (resultados) e realizar um loop para o que você deseja. Eu continuaria com os IFs, simples, claro e objetivo.

Answer (score 10):

Se você tem que manter as variáveis `Lstr_Resultado_N` pode adiciona-las em uma lista e usar o método [Count](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.7.2) para contar a quantidade de ocorrências de acordo com uma *condição* específica.

Veja um exemplo:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {                     
        string 
            resultado1 = "Verdadeiro", 
            resultado2 = "Verdadeiro", 
            resultado3 = "Falso", 
            resultado4 = "Verdadeiro";

        var valores = new List<string> {
                resultado1,
                resultado2,
                resultado3,
                resultado4,
        };
        var qtdVerdadeiro = valores.Count(x => x.Equals("Verdadeiro"));
        var qtdFalsos = valores.Count(x => !x.Equals("Verdadeiro"));

        WriteLine($"Qtd verdadeiro: {qtdVerdadeiro}");
        WriteLine($"Qtd falso: {qtdFalsos}");
    }
}
```

Saída:

> Qtd verdadeiro: 3
>   Qtd falso: 1

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bw2DfY).

Comment: Usei o seu exemplo porém me retornou 3 valores e nada mais. Talvez eu tenha respondido que eu manteria as variáveis no sentido de que eu tenho apenas 3 variáveis. Vou colocar o código por completo para que assim fique mais claro o código.

Comment: Eu percorro entorno de 100 arquivos nesse método.

Answer (score 6):

```
if ((Lstr_Resultado1 == "Verdadeiro") || (Lstr_Resultado2 == "Verdadeiro") || (Lstr_Resultado3 == "Verdadeiro")){
   Lint_TotalVerdadeiro++;
}
else{
   Lint_TotalFalso++;
}
```

Comment: Eu cheguei a tentar fazer desta forma anteriormente, mas acontece que quando o valor de Lstr_Resultado1 = verdadeiro e Lstr_Resultado2  = verdadeiro ele ira considerar o primeiro, anulando caso os dois seja verdadeiro tento apenas 1 resultado. Precisava que no caso Lint_TotalVerdadeiro fosse igual a 2.

Comment: é isso mesmo jovem.

Comment: Talvez eu não tenha sido claro o suficiente na minha dúvida. Vamos lá, eu tenho situações onde que eu posso ter 3x o resultado como verdadeiro. Resultado 1 = verdadeiro, Resultado2= verdadeiro e Resultado3= verdadeiro. Fazendo desta forma eu terei apenas 1 verdadeiro no meu total, sendo que eu tenho 3 verdadeiro.

Comment: Tinha votado como resposta mas depois pensei o mesmo. A questão é que você tem que testar cada uma das variáveis, que são diferentes, então não tem como fugir de sua solução. Uma pergunta, o valor atribuído as variáveis tem que ser string? Se for `bool` ficaria mais "elegante".

Comment: @LeandroAmarilha é por que eu preencho uma planilha no Excel com as variáveis, por isso deixei como string.

Comment: Entendido. O Albertt esclareceu sua dúvida, então

Comment: @PedroDuca Entendi! Então é isso mesmo, não vejo outra solução.